# check existing shared_ptr when using enable_shared_from_this in c++?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, reference-counting

Aside from catching the bad_weak_ptr error thrown when trying to call shared_from_this() on a pointer that is a raw pointer, is there a way of testing whether or not the object is being reference counted?

I have functions that deal with the raw pointer and shared pointer and I want to be sure that the error is obvious when using the wrong one? I can of course just catch the error, but I just wondered if there's an easy way of testing for this particular case?

Comment: Sounds like bad design to me. Maybe consider posting your code.

Comment: %union in yacc/bison only allows POD types, so I have to use pointers (this qs talks about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64958/what-is-the-best-way-of-preventing-memory-leaks-in-a-yacc-based-parser), however I wish to use smart pointers for the 'model' that is formed from the ast, hence I have to mix them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A call to `std::enable_shared_from_this<T>::shared_from_this()` will never fail for an existing valid object, or pointer to it. EDIT: ... if there is at least one instance of `std::shared_ptr<YourClass>` where `YourClass` is `std::enable_shared_from_this<YourClass>`. This is a stricter statement than the first one and I apologize if it was misunderstood.

You assure the validity of `shared_from_this()` by creating only `shared_ptr` instances of your classes. There is no way to check if a `YourClass` instance is managed by a `shared_ptr`, except of catching the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix raw pointers and managed pointers.

Comment: I have no choice, see comment above.